# how to set cron to display gui application

Tags: linux, cron

is it possible to show the results in terminal or any other gui by a cron.

for example I just write a script to show the time at terminal at each minute. but it does nothing. So is it possible to cron can show results in GUI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `DISPLAY` variable to `:0`. For instance:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; gedit
```

This crontab line will open the gui software gedit every minute.

Comment: This presumes that you have access to the `DISPLAY` you are attempting to connect to. On a single-user system where you are logged in, this may well be the case; but in general, this doesn't work either.